# Obtener valores de inputs dinamicos javascript

Tags: javascript, array, entrada

Estoy tratando de crear un arreglo bidimensional con datos dinamicos. Esos datos son pedidos al usuario a traves de unos inputs. El programa primero te pide el tamaño de la matriz y a partir de eso se generan unos inputs dinamicos con base en el orden que escogiste. El problema es que ya pude generar los inputs pero ahora no se como accesar a cada valor y guardar todo en un arreglo, bidimensional obvio.

Hasta ahora llevo esto:

HTML:

```
<select id="matriz" >
      <option selected>Ingrese el orden de la matriz</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <div class="" id="mostrarMatriz">

    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Mostrar matriz" id="btnMostrar">
```

Y el JS:

```
$("#btnMostrar").hide();

        $('#matriz').change(function(){


            $("#btnMostrar").show();

          var val = $(this).val();
          var innerhtml = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < val; j++) {
                innerhtml += "<input type='text' placeholder='' id='" + (j + 1) + "' name='" + (j + 1) + "' size=5>";

            }
            innerhtml+="<br>";

          }

          var display = $(this).next('#mostrarMatriz');
          display.html(innerhtml);
        });
```

Alguna idea de como obtener los valores y meterlos en un arreglo? gracias de antemano!

Comment: Agregar una clase general  y añadirlo a los input y luego iteras sobre estos elementos y vas añadiendo a un array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se podría seleccionar los `inputs` añadiéndoles una clase que los identifique. por ejemplo una clase `entrada` .  Para simular el ejemplo añadí valores de entrada y utilicé una variable temporal para añadir un `array` dentro de otro

```js
$("#btnMostrar").hide();
// Valor seleccionado del Select
let val = 0;
$('#matriz').change(function(){
  $("#btnMostrar").show();
  val = parseInt($(this).val());
  var innerhtml = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < val; j++) {
        innerhtml += "<input type='text' class='entrada' value='"+(j + i)+1+"' placeholder='' id='" + (j + 1) + "' name='" + (j + 1) + "' size=5>";
    }
    innerhtml+="<br>";
  }
  var display = $(this).next('#mostrarMatriz');
  display.html(innerhtml);
});

$("#btnMostrar").click(function(event) {
 let array = [];
  //Seleccionamos los inputs creados
 let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.entrada');
 let temp = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  //Añadimos al arreglo temporal para el 2D
  temp.push(inputs[i].value);
  //Si es igual al orden de la matriz
  // Entonces lo añadimos al array principal y
  // reseteamos el temporal
  if(temp.length == val){
   array.push(temp);
   temp= [];
  }
 }
 console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="matriz" >
  <option selected>Ingrese el orden de la matriz</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div class="" id="mostrarMatriz">

</div>

<input type="button" value="Mostrar matriz" id="btnMostrar">
```